# git status "could not open directory" "permission denied" errors

Tags: git, github

new to coding, command line, git
trying to follow along a video from an online course i'm taking, i messed up and freaked out and tried all these methods of deleting the repository because i thought unknown files were in there. now when i type git status all of these errors that didnt show before are popping up here [see photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnHxd.png). can somebody please tell me how to fix this so i can do my homework? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You initialized a git repository in your User-folder, which i think is not what you want.
Have you created a folder for your project? Then you can go to this directory with the cd command. In this folder you should create the git repository, and commands like git status will work.

Comment: i have created a folder, yes. how do i created the git repository? i already have one created in github. and when i do git clone in command line it says it already exists

Comment: If it exists, than that it sounds like you do have a folder locally with the project name.

Comment: i do, but the problem is somehow i messed it up and it shows a lot of untracked files and "warning: could not open directory 'Application Data/': Permission denied" when i do git status. so i dont know where to go from here. ive tried deleting the folder and cloning again but it will not let me, says directory is not empty

Comment: you can not delete the repository from command line, you would have to do this from windows explorer. but you dont want to do that, because there is no reason for it. Just try the command list command "ls" (without "" ;) ), then you will see all your folders and files. Then you just have to watch out for your project folder. then you go into the folder with the change directory command "cd nameoftheproject". After that git status etc will work

Comment: Let me explain it a little bit more clearly: 1: you have the git repository on github with an address like https://github.com/creator/projectname.git. You seem to know how to clone the repository with the command git clone and the link i mentioned before. Now the folder gets downloaded. You dont have to create a new folder by yourself. Git clone does this job by itself. Afterthat you go with cd projectname intoyour folder, and then everything should work just fine.